# Setting up the plotting region for text data using a dummy data frame

Tags: r, plot, text

I have a large number of data sets with utterances distinguished by the number of words they contain (4-word utterances, 5-word utterances, etc.). Each data set consists of a sample of exactly 1,000 utterance tokens and is stored in a data frame with 3 variables: the words ("word"), their grammatical tags ("c5"), and their position in the turn ("slot"):

```
df <- data.frame(word, c5, slot)
```

What I'd like to do is plot the dispersion of certain words within their utterances in a scatter plot by using the text() function and color codings, e.g., black for interjections, and grey for any other word type.
To set up the plotting region, I create a dummy frame with two variables: rows (for the words in the utterance) and slots (for each word's position in the utterance). For example, for the sample of 10-word utterances:

```
dummy <- data.frame(rows = 1:1000, slots = 1:10)
```

I then set up the plotting region for this data frame, thus:

```
plot(dummy$rows ~ dummy$slots, type="n", axes =F)
axis(1, at=seq(1:10), labels=c("w1", "w2", "w3", "w4", "w5", "w6", "w7", "w8", "w9", "w10"))
```

and fill in the slots with the data in the above dataframe "df":

```
for(i in unique(df$slot)){
  text(i, 1:1000, "_____", cex=1.45,
       col = ifelse(df[df$slot==i,]$c5=="ITJ", "black", "grey"))
}
```

This works fine as long as the rows in the dummy data frame are a multiple of the slots. The problem begins when they are not, e.g., in the case of 7-word utterances, I get this error:

```
dummy <-data.frame(rows = 1:1000, slots = 1:7)
Error in data.frame(rows = 1:1000, slots = 1:7) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1000, 7
```

Is there a way to set up the dummy data frame for the plot despite the mismatch between rows and slots?

Comment: This does not seem to be working: neither does this produce the correct sequence of labels on the x-axis nor does the for loop produce the right text() marks in the right places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to be more deliberate in choosing the size of your dummy dataset. A thousand is not a multiple of seven which is why you get the error. Have a look at the example below. In this example before creating the dataset, it's determined who big the first vector should be.

```
# Settings
slotSize <- 7
desiredRows <- 1000

# Compute nr of repeats
nrRepeats <- round(desiredRows / slotSize, 0)
totalRows <- nrRepeats * slotSize

# Create dummy data
dummy <-data.frame(rows = 1:totalRows, slots = 1:slotSize)
head(dummy); tail(dummy)
```

This can also be done in one line, though it may be harder to read.

```
# In one line
dummy <-data.frame(rows = c(1:(round((1000/slotSize),0) * slotSize)), slots = 1:slotSize)
```

Hopefully this will get you closer to the solution.